# $\epsilon y''+\sqrt{x}y'+y=0$, show there is no boundary layer at $x=1$ and a boundary layer of $\epsilon^{\frac{2}{3}}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: asymptotics, boundary-value-problem

I'm so lost. If I use quadratic formula I obtain that:
$$y(x) = ae^{-2\epsilon\sqrt{x}}+be^{-2x\sqrt{x}+2\epsilon\sqrt{x}}$$ with the boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$ but how does this lead to anything?

Comment: To check for a boundary layer near $x=1$, try setting $X = (1-x)/\delta$ and checking for balances.  If you find one, does the resulting leading order equation have a solution which decays as $X$ increases?

Comment: To find the width of the boundary at $x=0$, proceed as in your other question: set $X = x/\delta$ and check for balances, then find an appropriate solution to the new leading order equation which decays as $X$ increases.